# How to import a lot of data via Ruby on Rails API

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Let's say I have a phonebook-app that gets fed with contacts (name, phonenumber etc.) by other services over an API. One Import covers around 10,000 entries.

I'm now struggling developing this import-process. If there were just a few contacts to import I would suggest using default Ruby on Rails CRUD API (sending some POST requests to *myphonebookapp.com/contacts*). But I don't think it's a good idea to send 10,000 post-request at once.

Maybe it's better to create a route like *myphonebookapp.com/contacts/import* which takes an JSON-object with all 10,000 contacts. That would be one "giant" 3mb request, but I think at least that's better than the former idea.

Would that be the way to go or are there better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you consider feature with uploading text file with your 10000-entries dump, which could be parsed using RoR on the server?